# Antenna mutual coupling and estimation of angle of arrival

Tags: antenna, wireless, antenna-array

If I have two RX (receive) antennas at a distance of lambda/2 from each other there is a formula which relates the phase difference to the angle of arrival.
The formula is however assuming no mutual coupling between the two antennas .
Is there a formula that takes into consideration mutual coupling in order to calculate the error in estimating the angle of arrival?